# Adding and removing organizations to a network hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I would briefly like to know how it is possible to add a new organization to an existing Hyperledger fabric network. Also, how can an existing organization be removed (completely) from the network? Does everyone in the organization have to agree, etc?

Is it possible to remove peers from a certain channel, without removing them from the network? How can that be realized?

I am not looking for technical tutorials or anything, I would just like a brief comprehensive answer to understand how such things work within Hyperledger Fabric.